# PyCharm CPU intensive when working on a big project

Tags: pycharm

When I open a a folder as a project in PyCharm, that has a lot of files, it exhausts all my CPU cores. It's fine when there are few files.

I'm using Ubuntu and the "community" version of PyCharm. I'm new to PyCharm.

Anyone know what's causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PyCharm starts up, especially for the first time, it's traversing the directories to create its workspace.  If the files changes didn't originate with PyCharm, it needs to scan those to be aware of their contents (e.g. if you closed PyCharm, did a bunch of `sed` replacements, and then re-opened your project).

Additionally, if you look in the `.idea/` directory at the root of the project directory, you can see hints that it's setting up package inspection, associating and loading version control changesets with lines, and doing a number of other tasks.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what the problem was. I just opened up the big project again, and the CPU wasn't at a high percentage for long.